# Does my Android app's name have to exactly match its Play Store title?

Tags: android, google-play

Let's say my app is a web browser with a very non-web-browser-y name like "Widget". I want the app's name to be just "Widget" under its icon when you pull it up in the list of all the apps you have on your phone, but I would like its Google Play title to be "Widget (Web Browser)" so that it could actually be findable.

Is that actually possible? In Eclipse + ADT it says that the Application Name is the same as the app's title in the Play Store (which is what I'm hoping is not true) and I can't find anything to dispute that via searching, but I feel like I've seen apps do this before so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: What "All Apps" are you talking about? The Play Store or Settings app?

Comment: "All Apps" as in when you pull up all the apps you have installed on your phone (and also in the Settings app I suppose, sure).

EDIT: I clarified the question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

The name that is shown in "All Apps" is what you set against the attribute `android:label` under the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest`

The name that is shown in Google Play is what is set for `Title` in `Store Listing` tab while publishing your app